# Como plotar vários gráficos em várias páginas diferentes usando o ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho o seguinte data frame (df):

```
        Subject Period Treatment   Time      Concentration
1         1      1         A      -1.000         0.000
2         1      1         A      -0.500         0.000
3         1      1         A      -0.250         0.000
4         1      1         A       0.000         0.000
5         1      1         A       0.167         1.147
6         1      1         A       0.333         4.993
7         1      1         A       0.500         4.324
8         1      1         A       0.667         6.623
9         1      1         A       0.833         4.945
10        1      1         A       1.000         3.446
11        1      1         A       1.250         2.280
12        1      1         A       1.500         2.796
13        1      1         A       1.750         1.666
14        1      1         A       2.000         1.105
15        1      2         B      -1.000         0.000
16        1      2         B      -0.500         0.000
17        1      2         B      -0.250         0.000
18        1      2         B       0.000         0.000
19        1      2         B       0.167         2.378
20        1      2         B       0.333        24.137
21        1      2         B       0.500        22.876
22        1      2         B       0.667        25.779
23        1      2         B       0.833        27.178
24        1      2         B       1.000        19.609
25        1      2         B       1.250        13.392
26        1      2         B       1.500        10.431
27        1      2         B       1.750         7.402
28        1      2         B       2.000         6.793
29        2      1         B      -1.000         0.000
30        2      1         B      -0.500         0.000
31        2      1         B      -0.250         0.000
32        2      1         B       0.000         0.000
33        2      1         B       0.167         0.097
```

Este data frame poderá conter N sujeitos com M curvas de concentração por sujeito (que dependerá do número de tratamentos).

Para gerar os gráficos de concentração plasmática de cada sujeito estou utlilizando o seguinte código:

```
 p<- ggplot(Data, aes(x=Time, y=Concentration, group=Subject:Treatment:Period, shape=Treatment:Period,  color=Treatment)) + 
 geom_line() + geom_point(size=3) + facet_wrap(~ Subject,ncol = 2)+     scale_shape_manual(values=c(7,7,1,1)) + scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","darkblue"))+ xlab("Time (hr)")+
 ylab("Concentration (ng/mL)") + ggtitle("Individual Plasma Concentration - Drug X")
```

Meu problema é que quando o número de sujeitos é grande fica praticamente inviável ter uma boa visualização de todos os gráficos na mesma página (o tamanho reduz bastante). Logo, preciso da ajuda dos usuários "mais experientes" para aprimorar o código no sentido de controlar o número de gráficos que são impressos por página. Por exemplo, se tivermos 10 sujeitos e se desejarmos imprimir dois gráficos por página então teremos um total de 5 páginas com 2 gráficos por páginas. Já vi muita coisa no stackoverflow em inglês mas reconheço que não achei nenhum tão trivial. Será que isto é possível ser feito de uma forma elegante com poucas linhas de comando?

Muito obrigado e toda ajuda será muito bem vinda.

[image: Gráficos de concentração gerados]

Comment: Seria interessante disponibilizar ao menos uma parte não trivial do teu conjunto de dados através do output comando `dput`. Isto vai facilitar muito a vida de quem quiser te ajudar a resolver este problema.

Answer (score 4):

Gerei alguns dados aleatórios para conseguir fazer este gráfico. Creio que o código abaixo resolva o teu problema.

```
library(ggplot2)

Data <- data.frame(
    Subject=factor(rep(c(1:10), each=32)),
    Period=factor(rep(c(1,2), each=16, times=20)),
    Treatment=rep(c("A","B"), each=8, times=40),
    Time=rep(seq(-1, 2, length.out=8), 40),
    Concentration=rgamma(320, shape=2)
)

# numero de sujeitos no experimento
m <- length(unique(Data$Subject))

# numero de graficos por janela
k <- 2

# loop que vai criar as 5 janelas graficas

for (j in 1:ceiling(m/k)){

    # define os id dos pacientes que serao plotados na iteracao j
    id <- factor(((j-1)*k+1):(j*k))

    # grafico que sera plotado para cada k pacientes
    g <- ggplot(subset(Data, Subject %in% id), aes(x=Time, y=Concentration,
    group=Subject:Treatment:Period, shape=Treatment:Period,  color=Treatment)) +
    facet_wrap(~ Subject, nrow=k) + geom_line() + geom_point(size=3) +
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(7,7,1,1)) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","darkblue")) + 
    xlab("Time (hr)") + ylab("Concentration (ng/mL)") +   
    ggtitle("Individual Plasma Concentration - Drug     X")

    # plot acada uma das janelas graficas com k sujeitos
    print(g)
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu apenas escolhi quais sujeitos desejo no meu gráfico através do comando `subset`. Se forem poucos sujeitos, basta substituir os números deles dentro da chamada do conjunto de dados dentro do comando `ggplot`.

Comment: Bom dia Marcus, Muito obrigado pela contribuição!!! Mas o que eu realmente preciso é controlar o número de impressões por página a partir de um gráfico gerado no ggplot com o comando facet_wrap que normalmente é utilizado para criar subgráficos. Esta funcionalidade certamente ajudaria muitos membros deste fórum. Abraços.

Comment: A sua dica foi muito válida para quem deseja um subconjunto pequeno de gráficos, porém eu preciso ter acesso a todos os gráficos. Imagine se nos tivermos 1000 gráficos para serem construídos e precisarmos imprimir todos eles em um layout que tenha apenas dois por página. Esta é a situação que me refiro. Espero ter esclarecido a real necessidade.

Comment: Veja a edição que fiz. Creio que seja o output desejado.

Comment: Simplesmente sensacional este novo código! Abaixo fiz um aprimoramento dele para melhorar o aspecto da legenda gráfica. Por favor veja que as mudanças foram insignificantes para melhorar o que já estava muito bom!

Answer (score 1):

```
# número de sujeitos no experimento
m <- length(unique(Individual_Plasma_Concentration_BQL1$Subject))

# número de gráficos por janela
k <- 2

# loop que vai criar as 5 janelas gráficas

for (j in 1:ceiling(m/k)){

# define os id dos pacientes que serao plotados na iteração j
id <- factor(((j-1)*k+1):(j*k))

# gráfico que sera plotado para cada k pacientes
g <- ggplot(subset(Individual_Plasma_Concentration_BQL1, Subject %in% id),    aes(x=Time, y=Concentration, group=Subject:Treatment:Period,  shape=Treatment:Period,  color=Treatment:Period)) +
facet_wrap(~ Subject, nrow=k) + geom_line() + geom_point(size=3) +
scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,7,1,7)) +
scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","red","darkblue", "darkblue"))+ 
xlab("Time (hr)") + ylab("Concentration (ng/mL)") +   
ggtitle("Individual Plasma Concentration - Drug     X")

# plot acada uma das janelas graficas com k sujeitos
print(g)
}
```

Veja, que só alterei 3 linhas do seu código para melhorar o aspecto visual da legenda. Agora para fechar com chave de ouro, qual seria a linha de comando para que possamos exportar estes 5 gráficos (que podem ser "m" gráficos) para um documento novo do Microsoft Word?
Grande abraço e parabéns pela solução elegante....

Comment: O ideal seria fazer este questionamento a respeito da exportação de gráficos em uma nova pergunta, [conforme o site sugere](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2627/uma-nova-d%C3%BAvida-surge-ap%C3%B3s-a-pergunta-ser-respondida).

Comment: OK!!! farei esta pergunta pois sei que isto poderá ajudar muito aos usuários do pacote ggplot.